# Rails many to many token fields help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having that problem that my model dont want to save. I have a token field input for tags. 
I have followed this guide for the token input: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

I get this error when I try to create a new konkurrancer:

```
NoMethodError in Admin/konkurrancersController#create

undefined method `class_name' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/models/konkurrancer.rb:15:in `tag_tokens='
app/controllers/admin/konkurrancers_controller.rb:48:in `new'
app/controllers/admin/konkurrancers_controller.rb:48:in `create'

http://pastie.org/1834194

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"yo7wcAQl81tx3zZpPP44ENPYzYRZLpgyYKY+HK3yFKM=",
 "konkurrancer"=>{"name"=>"Vind en rejse",
 "banner2"=>"asdasd",
 "tracking"=>"sadasd",
 "vaerdi"=>"12222",
 "tid"=>"1 min",
 "tag_tokens"=>"1",
 "bedom"=>"2",
 "kategori_id"=>"9",
 "form"=>"Nyhedsbrev",
 "partner"=>"Iqmedier",
 "udtraekkes(3i)"=>"30",
 "udtraekkes(2i)"=>"4",
 "udtraekkes(1i)"=>"2011",
 "udtraekkes(4i)"=>"08",
 "udtraekkes(5i)"=>"26",
 "arrangeor"=>"",
 "note"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Opret konkurrence"}
```

My konkurrancer model:

```
class Konkurrancer < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :tag_tokens
  has_many :tagsmenus
  has_many :tags, :through => :tagsmenus
attr_reader :tag_tokens

  def tag_tokens=(ids)
    self.tag_ids = ids.split(",")
  end

end
```

My tag model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tagsmenus
has_many :konkurrancers, :through => :tagsmenus
has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true
before_save :assign_cached_slug, :unless => :cached_slug?

protected
  def assign_cached_slug
    self.cached_slug = self.name.gsub(/\s+/, '_').gsub(/[^\w\-]/, '')
  end

end
```

My tagmenu model:

```
class Tagsmenu < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

My controller:

```
def new
@konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.new  
respond_to do |format|
format.html # new.html.erb
format.xml  { render :xml => @konkurrancer }
end
end
  # POST /konkurrancers
  # POST /konkurrancers.xml
  def create
    @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.new(params[:konkurrancer])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @konkurrancer.save
        format.html { redirect_to(:admin_konkurrancers, :notice => 'Konkurrancer was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => :admin_konkurrancers, :status => :created, :location => @konkurrancer }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @konkurrancer.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I have created the join table and the model and also added the relation to my tag model.

Comment: Do you have a field in the model called `tag_ids`?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the corresponding model

Comment: I have found the solution defined the realtionship between tags and konkurrancer in tagsmenus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Tagsmenu < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :konkurrancer
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model has some conflicting statements.  You first define:

```
attr_accessor ... :tag_tokens
```

then later have:

```
attr_reader :tag_tokens
```

which is not necessary given the first line or vice versa given that later you have a deinition for the setter:

```
def tag_tokens(ids)
  self.tag_ids = ids.split(',')
end
```

I don't see `tag_ids` defined either given it is not a column in your table.  You should probably remove the `attr_accessor` definition for the `tag_tokens` and then define the `tag_ids` method for starters.

Comment: I dont have a column named tag_ids. Can you show me how my model should look like ? :)